# Limit vs Derivative

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am learning Calculus and I am confused over the difference between Limit and Derivative.

In the screenshot below, both the blue and red boxes come to the same conclusion of 3x^2.

So, why do we have 2 representations of the same outcome? As far as I understand, the derivative allows us to find the slope of the tangent line, and it seems that the limit equation does the same thing as well.

Comment: The derivative is a limit. Refer [difference quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

- the **derivative at a point** $x_0$ is defined by the limit (whether it exists) $$f'(x_0)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(x_0+\Delta x)-f(x_0)}{\Delta x}=3x_0^2$$

once we have defined the derivative at each point we can consider its value for all points of the domain such that the given limit exists and thus define the **derivative function** $f'(x)=3x^2$.

Comment: how do I rewrite the limit of $$x^3$$ using another form of the limit: $$f'(x_0)=\lim_{\Delta x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$
as compared to the one shown in blue in the screenshot?

Comment: @youcanlearnanything when we use $\Delta x$ usually we are considering $\Delta x=x-x_0\to 0$ and then $$f'(x_0)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(\Delta x)-f(x_0)}{\Delta x}$$

Comment: I made a typo, it should be x -> c. I am confused over the 2 different forms of limit, and I would like to know how it would be rewritten if it were to be f(x) - f(c)

Comment: @youcanlearnanything In taht case we have $$f'(c)=\lim_{x\to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$ which is equivalent to $$f'(c)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(\Delta x+c)-f(c)}{\Delta x}$$ for $\Delta x=x-c$.

Comment: if I were to use this form, I would have rewrite it as $$\lim_{x\to 0} {x^3-0\over x-0} = x^2$$ and the answer is different from $$3x^2$$

Comment: @youcanlearnanything in this case you are calculating the derivative to a specific point that is $x=0$ then $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0} {x^3-0\over x-0}  =\lim_{x\to 0} x^2=0$$ As I tried to explain in my answer you are making confusion with the $2$ different concept of derivative at one point and derivative function for a generic point $x$.

Comment: ok. I finally got it! thank you so much!

Comment: @youcanlearnanything You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

The concepts of a limit and derivative are totally different. One represents the idea of moving infinitely close to some input of a function and observing its behavior. Informally, a derivative is what happens when you measure the rate of change between two infinitely close points.

In just so happens that someone is *using the **definition** of a derivative* to show that a *certain* limit is equal to the derivative of some function. The derivative *is built upon* the limit and *is itself a limit*:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} {f(x+h)-f(x)\over h} = f'(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)-f(a)\over x-a} = f'(x)$$

The two are inherently related because limits are a mathematical tool to encapsulate what we are actually doing with a derivative, but they are not the same conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative *is* the limit formula. More so, the derivative is defined as$$\frac {df}{dx}=\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to0}\frac {f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$The reason why they produce the same answer is because they are the exact same formula. The derivative is calculated using the limit.