Is h in the limit definition of the derivative a constant or a variable?
Whenever someone explains the limit definition of the derivative they always talk about how $h$ approaches $0$.
I get the impression that h is a variable.

What is your question?

Is h a constant or a variable?

yes, $h$ varies to reach zero

@janmarqz h doesn't reach zero at all in the definition of limit

@David You should refer to the definition of limit to clarify the meaning of "h approaches 0".

Are you familiar with the definition of a limit? The constant $h$ does not take on successively smaller values. Given a positive $\epsilon$, there has to be a positive $\delta$ such that $\lvert h\rvert\lt\delta\implies\lvert\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)\rvert\lt\epsilon$.

Maybe related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4766378 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2772220

Technically @JohnDouma's antecedent should be $0<|h|<\delta$.

I am confused by the use of the phrases "h approaches" ,  "moving (infinitely) close ", ..

@David if the value of $h$ is "moving" then it can't be constant.  I like to think of limits in terms of tolerance from engineering problems. I want to machine a part by some process to be within some margin of error. The definition of a limit means given any margin of error on the output of that process I can find a margin of error on the inputs that forces it to be within that tolerance.

I think this is a good question but not one that is easily answered on a forum like this. Perhaps you could ask your teacher to go over this carefully with you?

The epsilon delta definition of a limit of a function $f$ approaching $L$ as $x$ approaches $y$ says that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there is some number $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies that $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.
In the case of the derivative we can think of $|x-y|$ as $|h-0|=|h|$. So we have for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $0 < |h|<\delta$ implies $|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)|<\varepsilon$.
So for every $\varepsilon$ that can occur, we can choose a $\delta$ to satisfy this. This means $\delta$ changes as $\varepsilon$ goes over every real number. Thus since we said that $|h|<\delta$, we have that $h$ must change with $\varepsilon$. So we can't guarantee that $h$ attains only one value due to its dependence on $\varepsilon$, thus it is a variable.
